# Read data from .Rdata File in C#

Tags: c#, r

I have requirement to read data from ".RData" files and process them in C# application. I could not find any API which I can use in C#, I believe there is an API for F# which I don't use as of now because of learning curve in F#.

Could anybody please suggest code or API to read ".Rdata" files?

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981755/it-is-possible-to-read-rdata-file-format-from-c-or-fortran

Comment: @42- how is this a duplicate of a quesiton for different programming languages?

Comment: Because there is no API for .Rdata files. In fact there's no guarantee that an rdata file from one version an be read by a different R version.

Comment: See this thread on R-help:  http://r-project.markmail.org/search/?q=API+.rdata#query:API%20.rdata+page:1+mid:3fevwtpavackl7li+state:results

Answer (score 0):

There's [R.NET](https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) which would allow you to execute the `load` function, then get the saved variables from the environment, maybe? My guess is you'll need to run something like

```
 engine.Evaluate("load('/my/data/dir/mydata.RData')");
 var data = engine.GetSymbol("myvariablename");
```