# Import RData file into C

Tags: c

I want to know how to import a RData file into C, the data file contains a series of integer.

I have already the method to import txt data file into C, but I do not know how to convert RData file into txt format.

Comment: Bill, please add some code, context, what do you have and what do you want to achieve. This will help others to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [It is possible to read .Rdata file format from C or Fortran?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981755/it-is-possible-to-read-rdata-file-format-from-c-or-fortran)

Comment: I have a RData file named "xx.RData" which contains several vectors and matrices. I want to import the data into C so that I can use them in C but I just do not know how to transfer the data.

Comment: R is open source, and written in C. You could read (or rip) the source code to read your file. Good luck!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to show us your efforts made so far. And please, don't hide additional informations in the comments, better [edit] your question.